# SSIS 2008 no possible to execute DTS 2000 package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm developping using BIDS 2008, I have a task which is Execute DTS 2000 package.
When running locally, it works fine ( I previsouly installed backward compatibility for 2005 and 2000 on my machine).
When deploying the package on a SQL server 2008 R2 and setting the sql agent to run it,the following error message appears:
stackoverflow System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040427): Execution was canceled by user

I also activated log in the DTS 2000 package and nothing is written in it..

So I guess I need to install some backward compatiblity files on the server as well, but which ones?
any idea?

Thanks

Comment: How complicated is the DTS2000 package?  It might be worthwhile to simply re-write it.  SQL2012 is already here, and you are going to be upgrading the server again sometime in the near future.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use DTS 2000 because I need to connect on Dbase files ( not available in 2005, 2008)

Comment: Try this:  http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/08/tip-connect-to-dbase-files-in-ssis/